# Formatting my Link field with multiple values

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I believe I have a way to do this, but as I'm learning I want to make sure I'm not doing it horribly wrong or reinventing a wheel that already exists (the module search on the Drupal site leaves a lot to be desired).

I've got a Link field with multiple values (just URLs). When this field is being rendered, I would like to sort of preprocess each of the URLs. If it's a youtube or vimeo link, I'd like to change it so that a video embed is rendered instead. If it's a link to an audio file (with certain extensions) then I want to render an html5 audio tag.  Else, I just want to render the link normally.

It looks like I could override `mytheme_field__links__mycontenttype()` (although I'm not exactly sure how to implement that method just yet, any examples are welcome).

It also looks like I could create a template in my theme named `field--links--mycontenttype.tpl.php`

Is this the right way to go?

Is one better than the other?

Do you have any links to a good example of how to implement/override these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two best ways to do this are the one you suggest by creating a tpl.php like you mention and doing your work in there directly.  Another (and preferred by many, but a bit more complex) is to use [template_preprocess_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7).

A very good explanation of how to go down the second route is http://www.digett.com/blog/01/18/2012/change-output-single-field-drupal-7-node

That way you don't end up with a whole bunch of field.tpls and you can isolate your changes in that function.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for the example link! It was exactly what I needed.

Comment: No problem. All credit due to the person who wrote that explanation.  I've used it myself. Very handy.